# Prove $\frac{\sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b} }{2} \leq \sqrt{ \frac{a+b}{2} }$

Tags: inequality

Could anyone help me to proof this inequality: $\frac{\sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b} }{2}  \leq \sqrt{  \frac{a+b}{2}  }$ for $a \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0$.

Comment: This is the AM-QM inequality applied to $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$.

Comment: ... or the concavity of the square root function ... or ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arithmetic mean <= Quadratic mean, proof?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129300/arithmetic-mean-quadratic-mean-proof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$‎\left( ‎\frac{\sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b} }{2} ‎\right) ‎^{2}‎‎ \leq ‎\left( ‎\sqrt{  \frac{a+b}{2}  }‎\right) ‎^{2}‎‎$ ‎$ ‎\Longleftrightarrow‎ ‎‎\left( ‎\sqrt{a}‎‎‎-‎\sqrt{b}‎‎\right)‎^{2}‎ ‎‎\geqslant ‎0‎ $‎

Comment: What we need here is a $\Leftarrow$ or $\Leftrightarrow$, not a $\Rightarrow$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that 
\begin{align*}
(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2 \ge 0 &\implies a+b \ge 2\sqrt{ab} \\
&\implies \frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab} \\
&\implies a+b \ge \frac{a+b}{2}+\sqrt{ab}\\
&\implies \frac{a+b}{2} \ge \frac{a+b+2\sqrt{ab}}{4} \\
&\implies \frac{a+b}{2} \ge\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{2}\right)^2\\
&\implies \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}} \ge \frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{2}
\end{align*}